# How to add dir.h library on linux c

Tags: linux, directory, console, c

I can't run my program because I can't add `dir.h` library on c

My Header File:

```
#ifndef _DIR
#define _DIR

typedef struct Path {
char         *name;         /* Name of directory */
int           refCount;     /* Number of paths with this directory */
int       hits;         /* the number of times a file in this
             * directory has been found */
Hash_Table    files;        /* Hash table of files in directory */
} Path;*/

void Dir_Init(void);
void Dir_InitDot(void);
void Dir_End(void);
Boolean Dir_HasWildcards(char *);
void Dir_Expand(char *, Lst, Lst);
char *Dir_FindFile(char *, Lst);
int Dir_MTime(GNode *);
void Dir_AddDir(Lst, char *);
char *Dir_MakeFlags(char *, Lst);
void Dir_ClearPath(Lst);
void Dir_Concat(Lst, Lst);
void Dir_PrintDirectories(void);
void Dir_PrintPath(Lst);
void Dir_Destroy(void *);
void * Dir_CopyDir(void *);

#endif /* _DIR */
```

and this is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include "dir.h"
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
printf("%d drives", _setdisk(2));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the output of your compiler? Specifically the error that it throws in relation to dir.h.

Comment: Please also include the compiler command itself (so we can see what include directives you are giving to the compiler)

Answer (score 0):

the header file include sequence should be so needed definitions for a header file are already defined.  Suggest:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include "dir.h"
```

Note: `dirent.h` needs the definitions found in `sys/types.h`

and `dir.h` needs the definitions found in `dirent.h`

So they should be in the appropriate order

Note: names beginning with an underscore followed by a capital letter are 'reserved' for the environment, to avoid name clashes, your code should not use that layout.  Suggest:

```
#ifndef DIR_H
#define DIR_H
```

note the name is all CAPS as that is the expected way to write a `#define` name.  Also note that the root words `DIR` and `H` are separated by an underscore as that is the expected way to separate root words in a `#define` name.

Note that it is best to separate a `struct` definition from a `typedef` and there is a extraneous `*/` after the end of the typedef. It is also best (although modern compilers can handle it) to write things to be easy for humans to read, without causing unnecessary confusion.  It is also a good programming practice to use "lowerCamelCase" for names.  Suggest:

```
struct pathStruct 
{
    char         *name;       /* Name of directory */
    int           refCount;   /* Number of paths with this directory */
    int           hits;       /* The number of times a file in this
                               * directory has been found */
    Hash_Table    files;      /* Hash table of files in directory */
};

typedef struct pathStruct Path;
```